# Rendering multiple partials in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render multiple partials in a controller, these will not be part of the response, but pushed to clients via [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) instead.

I'm using `render_to_string`.

When the second one is called, I get a `DoubleRenderError`.

How do I render a partial the way that `performed?` will not be affected?

Comment: It turns out `render_to_string` clears off "render results", so you can call it multiple times. The problem was that I called `render_to_string` in an `after_filter` hook, after a render was already called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out render_to_string clears off "render results", so you can call it multiple times. The problem was that I called render_to_string in an after_filter hook, after a render was already called.

Answer (score 1):

wait so how can you do this in a after_filter hook? cause im running into the same issue, and have to do an after_filter hook.

btw, im in a similar situation using push tech, but with HTML 5 websockets, and eventmachine

Comment: Try putting it just before the main render call in the controller action, instead of in an after_filter. I've looked into the source code and the render_to_string call manipulates the response, so you shouldn't call this after a render even if you manipulate the `@performed_render` variable.

Comment: ya, can't really do that. I'm using InheritedResources so after_filters are kinda the way I want to go.